# Find length of 2D array Python

Tags: python, arrays

How do I find how many rows and columns are in a 2d array?

For example,

```
Input = ([[1, 2], [3, 4], [5, 6]])`
```

should be displayed as 3 rows and 2 columns.

Comment: sounds like you should be using a numpy array, not a list of lists

Answer (score 181, accepted):

Like this:

```
numrows = len(input)    # 3 rows in your example
numcols = len(input[0]) # 2 columns in your example
```

Assuming that all the sublists have the same length (that is, it's not a jagged array).

Comment: So long as it's not a jagged array, this is ideal.

Comment: yo, I want to find sum of all element in that 2D array     def sum1(input):
        sum = 0
        for row in range (len(input)-1):
            for col in range(len(input[0])-1):
                sum = sum + input[row][col]
                
        return sum
    
    
    print sum1([[1, 2],[3, 4],[5, 6]])

It display 4 instead of 21 (1+2+3+4+5+6 = 21). Where is my mistake?

Comment: There's a simpler solution: sum(sum(x) for x in input)

Comment: @LongBodie: The mistake is that you subtract 1 from the lengths where you shouldn't. `Range(n)` already gives 0,1,...,**n-1** .

Answer (score 43):

You can use `numpy.shape`.

```
import numpy as np
x = np.array([[1, 2],[3, 4],[5, 6]])
```

Result:

```
>>> x
array([[1, 2],
       [3, 4],
       [5, 6]])
>>> np.shape(x)
(3, 2)
```

First value in the tuple is number rows = 3; second value in the tuple is number of columns = 2.

Comment: Thank you, I didn't want to use numpy for this thing

Answer (score 26):

In addition, correct way to count total item number would be:

```
sum(len(x) for x in input)
```

Comment: Great, this was exactly what I needed! In my case I can count all elements of a list up to 2nd degree: sum(len(x) if isinstance(x, list) else 1 for x in some_list)

Answer (score 11):

Assuming input[row][col],

```
    rows = len(input)
    cols = map(len, input)  #list of column lengths
```

Answer (score 1):

You can also use np.size(a,1), 1 here is the axis and this will give you the number of columns

Answer (score 0):

assuming `input[row][col]`

```
rows = len(input)
cols = len(list(zip(*input)))
```