# Finding out the number of lists with a certain length in Python

Tags: python

Given the following list of lists

```
arrayNumbers = [[32,3154,53,13],[44,34,25,67], [687,346,75], [57,154]]
```

how can I efficiently get the number of lists having only 4 items?

In this case, that would be `arrayNumbers_len = 2`. I can do this using a loop, but that is not efficient at all. Since the lengths of my real arrays are in the millions, I need a way to do this extremely fast.

Here is my current solution:

```
batchSize = 4
counter = 0
for i in range(len(arrayNumbers)):
    if (len(arrayNumbers[i]) == batchSize):
        counter += 1
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: That's a perfectly reasonable Python solution, and you aren't going to get around a loop (either explicitly or implicitly).

Comment: why is this tagged with `numpy`?

Comment: because i though that maybe there is a way to do it with numpy

Comment: But you are working with `list` objects, not `numpy.ndarray` objects, and anyway, you probably couldn't work easily with `numpy.ndarray` objects with "jagged" arrays...

Comment: i see, well if there is no way around it, then i will just use my current solution

Comment: @RaduS Sounds like an XY problem. Why you got an array of this strange shape ? If the source of the problem can be handled by numpy, it's possible that you don't need this strange array at all.

Comment: @RaduS see also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10713004/find-length-of-2d-array-python. I think this is what you are looking for. Sample `print "Number of rows: {}".format(len(arrayNumbers))`.

Comment: @RaduS which version of python are you using? If it's python 2, use list comprehension. If it's 3 use Prune's solution. See my timing results below.

Comment: i use python 3.5.4

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I went ahead and did some timings to show how these different approaches vary.

#### Note: These are in Python 3:

Note: `var_arr` has a million randomly-sized sublists:

```
In [31]: def for_loop(var_arr, batchsize):
    ...:     count = 0
    ...:     for x in var_arr:
    ...:         if len(x) == batchsize:
    ...:             count += 1
    ...:     return count
    ...:

In [32]: def with_map_count(var_arr, batchsize):
    ...:     return list(map(len, var_arr)).count(batchsize)
    ...:

In [33]: def lambda_filter(var_arr, batchsize):
    ...:     len(list(filter(lambda l: len(l) == batchsize, var_arr)))
    ...:

In [34]: def sum_gen(var_arr, batchsize):
    ...:     sum(len(x) == batchsize for x in var_arr)
    ...:

In [35]: from collections import Counter
    ...: def with_counter(var_arr, batchsize):
    ...:     Counter(map(len, var_arr)).get(batchsize, 0)
    ...:

In [36]: %timeit for_loop(var_arr, 4)
82.9 ms ± 1.23 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10 loops each)

In [37]: %timeit with_map_count(var_arr, 4)
48 ms ± 873 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10 loops each)

In [38]: %timeit lambda_filter(var_arr, 4)
172 ms ± 3.76 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10 loops each)

In [39]: %timeit sum_gen(var_arr, 4)
150 ms ± 3.12 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10 loops each)

In [40]: %timeit with_counter(var_arr, 4)
75.6 ms ± 1.1 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10 loops each)
```

Some more timings:

```
In [50]: def with_list_comp_filter(var_arr, batchsize):
    ...:     return len([x for x in var_arr if len(x) == batchsize])
    ...:
    ...: def with_list_comp_filter_map(var_arr, batchsize):
    ...:     return len([x for x in map(len, var_arr) if x == batchsize])
    ...:
    ...: def loop_with_map(var_arr, batchsize):
    ...:     count = 0
    ...:     for x in map(len, var_arr):
    ...:         count += x == batchsize
    ...:     return count
    ...:

In [51]: %timeit with_list_comp_filter(var_arr, 4)
87.8 ms ± 4.35 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10 loops each)

In [52]: %timeit with_list_comp_filter_map(var_arr, 4)
62.7 ms ± 1.63 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10 loops each)

In [53]: %timeit loop_with_map(var_arr, 4)
91.9 ms ± 1.43 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10 loops each)
```

Comment: What about the list comprehension `len([l for l in arrayNumbers if len(l) == 4])` (DBedrenko's 2nd solution). I ran some tests and that came out to be the fastest. Would be good if you could independently confirm.

Comment: @pault it's definitely not, the `list(map(len, arr)).count(4)` is the fastest so far

Comment: Interesting. I reran my tests with a million elements and I get the list comp to be fastest with the `list(map(len, arr)).count(4)` coming in second. Here is how I made my test array: `arrayNumbers = [[np.random.randint(0, 10)]*np.random.randint(0, 10) for _ in range(1000000)]`

Comment: @pault are you using Python 2?

Comment: Yes python2. I was just about to add that to my comment.

Comment: @pault yes, then use `map(len, arr).count(4)`, using `list` makes you iterate over the million elements again unnecessarily (a testament to it's speed, given that it still comes in second)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/165992/discussion-between-pault-and-juanpa-arrivillaga).

Answer (score 3):

Would this be of acceptable performance?

```
len([l for l in arrayNumbers if len(l) == 4])
```

If this is still too slow, you can write the algorithm in C or C++, and call this from your Python code. See more here for details: https://docs.python.org/3.6/extending/extending.html

Comment: @miradulo My thoughts are that `filter` being part of the core Python library, would be well optimized. At least more optimized than manually writing the loop at "low level" in Python (or reinventing `filter()` by yourself in Python) . Ideally `filter()` is one of the functions that's implement in C in CPython.

Comment: `filter` + `lambda` will tend to be slow. `filter` + built-in function will perform nicely. list-comprehensions woudl be better in this case, since it isn't a built-in, and you can avoid the function-call overhead of calling the lambda a million times (which is high in Python)

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga Thanks for the tip, I learnt something today :)

Answer (score 3):

Sorry, but just in raw Information Science terms, you're stuck with an **O(N)** problem, where **N** is the number of elements in your list.  You have to access each length to test it against `batchSize`.  With that, however, we can stuff it into a one-liner that gives Python a chance to optimize as best it can:

```
map(len, arraynumbers).count(4)
```

Comment: In python 3.x, I believe you need `list(map(...))`. But I don't think creating a list is necessary (see my solution).

Comment: @jpp yeah but this will almost certainly be faster than anything involving a generator expression. Generators tend to be slow (there's a lot of overhead to generators). Check out my benchmarks

Comment: Yup you are probably right. Both generators and lists have overheads, will need to do more research to see which has more and why.

Comment: The OP's hope was that by using `numpy` the **O(N)** problem could be performed with compiled code, which runs orders of magnitude faster than interpreted Python.  But `numpy` doesn't provide this kind of building block.

Answer (score 2):

I ran my own tests in python 2 and it appears that list comprehension (@DBedrenko's updated solution) is the fastest with @Prune's `map(len, arraynumbers).count(4)` coming in second:

```
nLists = 1000000
arrayNumbers = [[np.random.randint(0, 10)]*np.random.randint(0, 10) for _ in range(nLists)]
batchSize = 4
In [67]:

%%timeit
counter = 0
for i in range(len(arrayNumbers)):
    if (len(arrayNumbers[i]) == batchSize):
        counter += 1
10 loops, best of 3: 108 ms per loop
In [68]:

%%timeit
map(len, arrayNumbers).count(4)
10 loops, best of 3: 65.7 ms per loop
In [69]:

%%timeit
len(list(filter(lambda l: len(l) == 4, arrayNumbers)))
10 loops, best of 3: 121 ms per loop
In [70]:

%%timeit
len([l for l in arrayNumbers if len(l) == 4])
10 loops, best of 3: 58.6 ms per loop
In [71]:

%%timeit
sum(len(i)==4 for i in arrayNumbers)
10 loops, best of 3: 97.8 ms per loop
```

Comment: So, Python 2's list-comprehension implementation relies on a hack which essentially shares the local scope wherever it is (which is why it has "leaky" scope]. In Python 3, it get's it's own scope. This may be the cause of the difference, but I'm not too deeply aware of the implementation details to even speculate, really.

Answer (score 2):

Here is a numpy solution. It is only marginally slower than the best of the non-numpy answers. One advantage would be that one could get the counts for all lengths at minimal additional cost unless there are ridiculously large sublists:

```
>>> import numpy as np
>>> from timeit import timeit
>>> from collections import Counter
>>> 
>>> lengths = np.random.randint(0, 100, (100_000))
>>> lists = [l * ['x'] for l in lengths]
>>> 
>>> 
# count one
# best Python
>>> list(map(len, lists)).count(16)
974
# numpy
>>> np.count_nonzero(16==np.fromiter(map(len, lists), int, len(lists)))
974
>>> 
# count all
# best Python
>>> [cc for c, cc in sorted(Counter(map(len, lists)).items())]
[973, 1007, 951, 962, 1039, 962, 1028, 999, 970, 997,
 ... 
 1039, 997, 976, 1028, 1026, 969, 1106, 994, 1002, 1022]
>>> 
# numpy
>>> np.bincount(np.fromiter(map(len, lists), int, len(lists)))
array([ 973, 1007,  951,  962, 1039,  962, 1028,  999,  970,  997,
       ...
       1039,  997,  976, 1028, 1026,  969, 1106,  994, 1002, 1022])
```

Timings:

```
>>> kwds = dict(globals=globals(), number=100)
>>> 
>>> timeit('list(map(len, lists)).count(16)', **kwds)
0.38265155197586864
>>> timeit('np.count_nonzero(16==np.fromiter(map(len, lists), int, len(lists)))', **kwds)
0.4332483590114862
>>> 
>>> timeit('Counter(map(len, lists))', **kwds)
0.673214758047834
>>> timeit('np.bincount(np.fromiter(map(len, lists), int, len(lists)))', **kwds)
0.43800772598478943
```

Answer (score 1):

Using `filter` with an anonymous function:

```
>>> Numbers = [[32,3154,53,13],[44,34,25,67],[687,346,75],[57,154]]
>>> filter(lambda x: len(x) == 4, Numbers)
[[32, 3154, 53, 13], [44, 34, 25, 67]]
>>> len(filter(lambda x: len(x) == 4, Numbers))
2
```